# C++: Map of functions accepting any arguments and return value

Tags: c++11, argument-passing, stdmap, std-function

**Is it possible, and how, can I have a `std::map` of functions that can take any number of arguments and return any type that can be converted to a `std::string`?**

What I have tried was using `std::function` but when declaring the `std::map` I still always had to specify the type of the arguments that the function can allow. e.g. `std::map<int,std::function<`**INT, BOOL**`>>`.

I have also tried multiple variations of variadic functions and derived classes but none seemed to have given me what I need.

I've also seen some lambda examples that I didn't quite understand but still not sure if that was the right approach.

In principle what I am trying to achieve is to have a function of any type or form bound to each key that can be pressed on the keyboard. See image of how I imagined this map visually would look like: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Hmu.png)
When pressing a key, the function corresponding with the colour of the key, must be called.

Answer (score 0):

You may have one or more piece of code that call these functions depend on the key stroke:

```
if (key_pressed == 'q') {
  f3(some_boolean_variable);
} else if (key_pressed == 'f') {
  f4(some_string_variable);
}
```

Even you have some way to use a map from key to function, you can't specify how these variables are picked and passed in to the chosen function without enumerating all functions (aka, use a map).

My suggestions:

1) Use lambda capture and `std::bind` for what you already have when generating (not calling) these functions.

```
std::map<char, std::function<void(int)>> m;
m['m'] = [](int) {...};
string s = ... // suppose you already know what s should be.
m['i'] = [s](int) {...};
```

2) Try to redesign to use the same signature, e.g. `std::function<void(const ContextData&)>`

```
using std::experimental::optional;
using std::tuple;
struct ContextData {
  optional<bool> bool_value;
  optional<tuple<int, string>> f2_args;
  optional<tuple<int, string, bool, float, int, int, int>> f5_args;
};
```

Notice that above may solve your problem in a crappy way, but it's not a good design. Use this "a bunch of optional values" pattern only if it looks clean, is easy to understand and makes sense.

3) If you can't come up with a clean ContextData, use `boost::variant` or even `boost::any`. Use them wisely.

```
std::map<char, std::function<void(boost::any)>> m;
using std::tuple;
using std::tie;
using boost::any;
using boost::any_cast;
m['i'] = [](any data) {
  int i;
  std::string s;
  // May throw.
  tie(i, s) = any_cast<tuple<bool, std::string>>(data);
  // use i and s
};
```

If I were you, I will do a redesign to make the parameter lists consistent. It's not just for making compiler happy though; it's more like organizing the logic in a rational, non-ad-hoc way.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Your suggestions all are great but your last sentence actually answers it quite nicely. I want to keep it flexible but it might cause some disorganization (like you are suggesting). I do have one thing I want to try with the lambda then I will redisgn.

Comment: Got it working exactly the way I wanted. Thanks again @TimShen